# I have to remove the / and my colleague have to put it

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

We have a very strange problem with this code:

```
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'admin / quickEdit',
    data: {
```

We are a team of developers, when I test the site locally on my computer, I have to remove the character "/" from the URL:

```
url: 'admin / quickEdit',
```

on the other hand, my colleagues must put it ... so:

```
url: '/ admin / quickEdit',
```

If I don't put it, I have a 404 error.

I work under MAMP and my colleagues under craftsman serve.

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The spaces in that URL are ... odd.

Comment: The three lines of "code" you've provided do not help to understand the problem. What have you tried to debug the problem? Why not use the same settings on all development machines?

Comment: I think this all comes because in the routes/(web.php or api.php) you have something like: `Route::post('admin/quickEdit')` try to add the slash there`Route::post( '/admin/quickEdit');`

Answer (score 3):

The URL `admin / quickEdit` is *relative* to the page where the ajax is being done. So if it's on the page `https://example.com/foo/bar`, then it posts to `https://example.com/foo/bar/admin / quickEdit`.

The URL `/ admin / quickEdit` is relative to the root of the site. So if it's on the page `https://example.com/foo/bar`, then it posts to `https://example.com/admin / quickEdit` (no `/foo/bar` in there).

If you need to not have it and your colleque needs to have it, it suggests that:

- You're using it on different pages and on one of them, it's appropriate that it be page-relative, but on another it's appropriate that it be root-relative.
- Your servers are handling routes differently.

It's hard to provide more without further details.